# How can we decide that an integer is power of 2 by using bit manipulation?

Tags: python, c++, bit

For example if the given number n = 16
If it is power of 2 then the output should be true else false, i want the answer by using bit manipulation.

Comment: If the number is a power of two, then there is only one 1 bit in the entire number.  Also, `n & (n-1)` will be 0.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please elaborate by taking an example it would help me a lot !! Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Kushal_Hemanth try running the code I share. Also, read the explanation on GeeksforGeeks. Hope this helps

Comment: @ShisuiOtsutsuki i have udneestood that thanks for you help !!

Comment: @Kushal_Hemanth if the answers help you try to mark them ok because that helps other people as well. Thanks!

Comment: If using C++, you might want to check out [std::has_single_bit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit)

Comment: @BoP, good utility function, but works only with compilers supporting C++ 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution mentioned by @TimRoberts is the most simple way of using bit manipulation.

Just check `if (n & (n - 1) == 0)`. Why does this work?

Assume n = 8 (1000 in base 2), then n - 1 = 7 (0111 in base 2). If you do a bitwise AND of these two, you get 0. This is true for n equal to any power of 2.

So you function should simply be:

```
bool is_power_of_2(unsigned long n)
{
    return n != 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this incorrectly reports 0 to be a power of two. You should account for that, for example like `return n && !(n & (n - 1))`. You can also find this solution in [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) wonderful resource for bit manipulation hacks by Sean Eron Anderson.

Comment: @JakobStark, thanks for pointing this out. Made the edits.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? Source [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-whether-a-given-number-is-power-of-2/):

```
def isPowerOfTwo(n):
    cnt = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n & 1 == 1:
            cnt = cnt + 1
        n = n >> 1
 
    if cnt == 1:
        return 1
    return 0

# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # Function call
    if(isPowerOfTwo(31)):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
 
    if(isPowerOfTwo(64)):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

**Explanation:**

All powers of 2 have only 1-bit set in them

Examples: `2 --> 10`, `4 --> 100`, `8 --> 1000`, `16 --> 10000`, so on

Comment: Your function will return `1` when `n == 1`. I don't think `1` is considered a power of 2.

Comment: you can use if and else if it reurns 1 then yes otherwise no

Comment: nevermind, I had a brain fart.

Comment: Or, better, just use [std::has_single_bit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit).

Comment: @JesperJuhl, that would work only if the compiler supports C++ 20. But yes, it's a good utility function.